# How to set custom format for datetimepicker in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I just want to ask something, can I use a 12/10/93 date format in datetimepicker in VB.Net? mm/dd/yy specifically. If I can, how?

Comment: Select the DateTimePicker and look at the Properties window.  You can't really miss the CustomFormat and Format properties.

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem, I really didn't notice the CustomFormat option.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the properties window for your DateTimePicker, set Format to Custom, then set CustomFormat to `MM/dd/yy`, note the upper case `MM`, lower case is reserved for minutes.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem, I really didn't notice the CustomFormat option.